# convert tuple of tuple to list of tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

Want to convert a list of tuples of tuples into a list of tuples and remove the element '0' from the resulting list:

```
[(5, ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'speedlimit', 'id')), (5, ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'speedlimit', 'distanceStdDev'))]
```

expected:

```
[('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'id', 5), ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex','speedlimit', 'distanceStdDev', 5)]
```

Code I've tried:

```
# Your list of tuples of tuples
list_of_tuples_of_tuples = [(5, ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'speedlimit', 'id')), (5, ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'speedlimit', 'distanceStdDev'))]
result_list = [tuple(filter(lambda x: x != 0, inner_tuple)) for outer_tuple in list_of_tuples_of_tuples for inner_tuple in outer_tuple]
print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_tuples_of_tuples = [(5, ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'speedlimit', 'id')), (5, ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'speedlimit', 'distanceStdDev'))]
res=[]
for a,b in list_of_tuples_of_tuples:
    tmp=tuple(i for i in b if i!=0)+tuple(i for i in [a])
    res+=[tmp]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write a small helper function it will keep the list comprehension more concise/readable. Something like this:

```
def mt(a, b):
    return tuple(e for e in b if e != 0) + (a,)


lot = [
    (5, ("RoadAttributes", "egoInformationCompex", 0, "speedlimit", "id")),
    (5, ("RoadAttributes", "egoInformationCompex", 0, "speedlimit", "distanceStdDev")),
]
nlot = [mt(*e) for e in lot]
print(nlot)
```

**Output:**

```
[('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'id', 5), ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'distanceStdDev', 5)]
```

Of course, if you prefer a one-liner then it's just:

```
nlot = [tuple(e for e in b if e != 0) + (a,) for a, b in lot]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify original list in-place:

```
list_of_tuples_of_tuples = [
    (5, ("RoadAttributes", "egoInformationCompex", 0, "speedlimit", "id")),
    (5, ("RoadAttributes", "egoInformationCompex", 0, "speedlimit", "distanceStdDev")),
]

for i, tup in enumerate(list_of_tuples_of_tuples):
    target_tuple = tup[1]
    if 0 in target_tuple:
        list_of_tuples_of_tuples[i] = (tuple(val for val in target_tuple if val != 0) + (tup[0],))

print(list_of_tuples_of_tuples)
```

Output

````
[('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'id', 5), ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'distanceStdDev', 5)]```
````

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, looks like you do want the 5 at the end.

Output:

```
[('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'id', 5), ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'distanceStdDev', 5)]
```

Code:

```
list_of_tuples_of_tuples = [(5, ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'speedlimit', 'id')), (5, ('RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'speedlimit', 'distanceStdDev'))]
result_list = [tuple(i for i in b if i!=0)+(a,) for a,b in list_of_tuples_of_tuples]
print(result_list)
```